# Upload binary data from Safari, without user selecting a file

Tags: ajax, upload, safari, binary, xmlhttprequest

There are several HTML5 features (BlobBuilder, ArrayBuffer) and pre-HTML5 hacks (`charset=x-user-defined`) used to handle binary data in `XMLHttpRequest`.

As far as I can tell, nothing can make Safari upload binary data that isn't in a file interactively selected by the user, and transmitted as `"multipart/form-data"`.

In fact, the data I'm trying to send is already in the filesystem, and I have a `file://` URL to it. This is a PhoneGap app. But there's no way to get the browser to accept that due to the security risk, and PhoneGap's FileTransfer feature is useless because it lacks progress bar support.

At this point, I'm willing to totally throw compatibility out since the HTML and JavaScript files will be downloaded and stored client side. And the app already requires an iPhone 4 so I can demand a recent browser version. Is there any way to make Safari 5.1 upload in binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps File Uploader plugin for Phonegap ([iOS version](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/FileUploader), [iPhone version](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/FileUploader)) can help? It has a progress callback.

> `progress` Called on upload progress. Signature should be `function(bytesUploaded, totalBytes)`

Example from the docs:

```js
window.plugins.fileUploader.uploadByUri(
    'http://example.com/upload',
    'file://path/to/file.jpg', 
    {foo: 'bar'}, 
    'myPhoto', 
    'anImage.jpg',
    'image/jpeg', 
    function(result) {
        console.log('Done: ' + result);
    }, 
    function(result) {
        console.log("Error: " + result);
    }, 
    function(loaded, total) {
        var percent = 100 / total * loaded;
        console.log('Uploaded  ' + percent);

    }
);
```

Comment: Think I saw a reference to that earlier… is it the ancestor of the bundled FileTransfer plugin? It appears the "iOS" version is more up to date than the "iPhone" version: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/FileUploader . And the interface is incompatible with the Android version. For now, I'm just biting the bullet and uploading in Base64. If Apple wants their apps to run slower than Android, it's their prerogative :vP .

Comment: You're right, the iPhone version references PhoneGap instead of Cordova. Hope the Base64 uploading works just as well, even if slower.